# How to pass values values when creating an object

Tags: php

I am using php 5.3.6.

When I create a new object, the following works:

```
$my_object = new my_clas();
```

But what if I wanted to pass values, such as this:

```
$my_object = new my_clas( $value1 , @value2 );
```

Where would those values go? Do they go to the __construct function or can I target a specific function?

Note: Right now I have a class with a __construct function and I am doing the above (e.g., passing values) and everything works fine, but I am wondering if this is just a happy accident or something I should worry about.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The will be passed to the `__construct` function, always. If you want to pass them to another function from there, then call it inside `__construct`

Comment: I know this is quasi unrelated, but . . . is there a way for the __construct to know the name of the object being instantiated?

Comment: @HumanBacon if you mean the name of the whole class like `my_clas` in your example then you can use `__CLASS__`. You can't get the name of the object itself from within the constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
$my_object = new my_clas( $value1 , @value2 );
```

The params will be passed to the constructor.

If you want to pass it to other function in the class you can do:

```
$my_object = new my_clas();
$my_object->myfunction($value1, $value2);
```

Or let the constructor handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` is not PHP.

```
class my_clas{
    function __construct($value1,$value2){
        //Here you can play with $value1 and $value2
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it is. It suppresses the warning when PHP fails to find a constant named value2 and treats "value2" as a string instead :P

Comment: Actually, in this case, the @ was a typo on my part. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

another idea could be is you pass the values into the page as your code would suggest

```
$myClassTest = new ClassTest($value1, $value2)
$myData = $myClassTest->getValue2();
```

and in the class

```
class ClassTest
{

    private $value1;
    private $value2;

    __construct($value1, $value2)
    {
         $this->value1 = $value1;
         $this->value2 = $value2;
    }

    function getValue2()
    {
        return $this->value2;
    }

}
```

this way, you can always call the getValue for the data you require. i normally create this for all variables that i would have in a class. great for testing a class.

also if you want to set a value add

```
function setValue2($value2)
{
    $this->value2 = $value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you instantiate a class, the called method is __construct or other with the same name that the class if you aren't using namespaces since PHP 5.3.3

More info about constructors:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

And for the deprecated use of methods called with the same name that the class if you are using namespaces:
http://php.net/releases/5_3_3.php